# Kali Linux - No internet, neither wired or wifi

Tags: networking, kali-linux

I have installed Kali Linux (dual boot on Mac Pro 15).
When I login to my mac everything works just fine - but when I login to my kali Linux I do not have any internet connection. No wires or wifi.
When I go to Settings -> Network - it just say: 'Oops, something went wrong. Please contact your software disti/partner'

Can anybody help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

When you set up kali, do not fly through it. There's a section in there that prompts you for your wireless passphrase and broadcast name.

Install your sources.

Then run the commands as follows.

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```